# css selector java server faces tags

Tags: css, jsf

I'm implementing a dropdown list with jsf tags (commandLinks).

I have question about css selector in jsf.

When I hover on a commandLink class "about" I want to change font color of the other 2 commandLinks to red.

Here is my attempt:

In css file

```
.about:hover .sub{
    color: red;
}


<h:commandLink styleClass="about" value="About us ▾" action="/about"/>
<h:commandLink styleClass="sub" value="test1"    action="/customers"/>
<h:commandLink styleClass="sub" value="test2" action="/license" />
```

but nothing changes. I also tried this

```
.about:hover > .sub{
    color: red;
}
```

It didn't work either.

Comment: can you make a JSFiddle , or Codepen ?

Comment: its java server faces tags and CSS. I can't compile on JSFiddle. It has nothing to do with javascript i think.

Comment: Your links have no childrens... are you doing a menu? You may need `ul` / `li`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing things in your menu, you need to understand the parent / children concept. The `css` selector `.about .sub` will select childrens `sub` with a parent `about`. In your case you have no hierarchy at all.

Almost all menus are using this simple concept :

```
<ul>
    <li class="about">
        <h:commandLink value="About us ▾" action="/about"/>
        <ul class="sub">
            <li><h:commandLink value="test1" action="/customers"/></li>
            <li><h:commandLink value="test2" action="/license" /></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <!-- ... other top level menus ... -->
</ul>
```

Now your css selector will work :

```
.about:hover > .sub {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Alexandre. I changed everything u suggested but it still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @user3079777 I've just removed `styleClass` for `h:commandLink` since they are not used, so it should work...